# S/pS is uncountable

Tags: ring-theory

From Page 163 of Rotman's Homological Algebra book:

The direct product of countably many Z is not free.

In the proof, a subgroup S is defined where S = {tuples with countably many components: each positive power of p divides almost all components}. He was trying to show that S is not free.

Then he deduced that S is uncountable. And were S a free abelian group, then S/pS would be uncountable, for S = + C's (where + is direct) implies S/pS is isomorphic to + (C/pC).

I am not quite sure how to see by the argument he gave that S/pS would be uncountable. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you! been looking for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S$ were a free Abelian group, it would be a direct sum of $\mathfrak a$ copies
of $\Bbb Z$ for some cardinal $\mathfrak a$. Then $S/pS$ would be a direct sum of
$\mathfrak a$ copies of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Therfore $|S/pS|\ge\mathfrak a$
since $S/pS$ contains a generating set of size $\mathfrak a$. We know that
$S/pS$ is countable so $\mathfrak a$ is a countable cardinal. This means that $S$
must also be countable, which we know isn't true.

Comment: One question, Angina. By Z/Z, you mean Z/pZ, correct?